# CUDA Visual Studio Integration Installation failure

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, windows-10

I am trying to install CUDA 7.5 on Windows 10 with both VS 2013 Community and VS 2015 Community installed. The CUDA installer correctly detects VS2013, and installs the CUDA library correctly, but fails when attempting to install CUDA Visual Studio Integration tools. Are there any possible fixes for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say much about VS 2013 without any more details about error messages etc. It should work, though. I was able to install the same combination.
CUDA 7.5 does not support VS 2015. Even CUDA Toolkit 8.0 RC supports only Visual Studio 2015 up to Update 1, but not Update 2 or 3.